# True or False to show route-item in navbar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

im building a website and using vvue with vue-router.
My Navbar component iterates through the routes element and gets all routes to show in the navbar, so i can simply add and remove routes without changing the navbar component.
Now i want for example the Data protection notice or the legal notice not to show up.

I tried to solve this with a boolean and a v-if. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

My code looks as following:

**Navbar component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mdheader"></div>
    <div class="md-layout-item">
      <md-tabs md-sync-route class="md-primary" md-alignment="centered">
        <div
          v-for="r in this.$router.options.routes"
          :key="r.name"
          :v-if="r.showOnBar"
        >
          <md-tab :md-label="r.name" :to="r.path" exact></md-tab>
        </div>
      </md-tabs>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "navbar"
};
</script>
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    showOnBar: true
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    showOnBar: true,
    component: () => import("@/views/About.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/aktuelles",
    name: "Aktuelles",
    showOnBar: true,
    component: () => import("@/views/Aktuelles.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/datenschutz",
    name: "Datenschutz",
    showOnBar: false,
    component: () => import("@/views/Datenschutz.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

export default router;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youa re very close, but you need to wrap your custom property in meta option:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    meta: { showOnBar: true }
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    meta: { showOnBar: true }
    component: () => import("@/views/About.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/aktuelles",
    name: "Aktuelles",
    meta: { showOnBar: true },
    component: () => import("@/views/Aktuelles.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/datenschutz",
    name: "Datenschutz",
    meta: { showOnBar: false }
    component: () => import("@/views/Datenschutz.vue")
  }
];
```

and access it via `route.meta.showOnBar`. Keep in mind that you only need to define it for routes you want to show on your navbar.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Unfortunately your solution does not work at my code. Maybe i have a wrong iteration?

<md-tabs md-sync-route class="md-primary" md-alignment="centered">
        <md-tab
          v-for="r in this.$router.options.routes"
          :key="r.name"
          :v-if="r.meta.showOnBar"
          :md-label="r.name"
          :to="r.path"
          exact
        ></md-tab>
      </md-tabs>

Answer (score 0):

You [need to wrap your custom route properties into `meta`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)  as stated in BroiSatse's answer.

However, another issue is that you used `:v-if` (i.e. you bound the `v-if` attribute) instead of just using `v-if`. `v-if` already evaluates the condition in the value as [per the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

Here's a sandbox to play around with: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-q-62409392-6zovw?file=/src/router/index.js

Comment: Thanks alot. Havent seen this little mistake. Its working now. :)